# namespacing 3rd party js libs using rails 3 asset pipeline

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I'm using the Rails3 asset pipeline for js.  I'd like to wrap some third-party libs in a namspace, but I can't get it to work.  For example, this

```
var myns= function() {
//= require swfobject
};
```

produces literally:

```
var myns= function() {
//= require swfobject
};
```

That is, the `require` wasn't invoked.  Is the asset pipeline syntax so fragile?  Where is this limitation documented?  Is there a workaround or better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First time I see this use case of assets pipeline.
Anyway you should check the sprockets documentation https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets (The Directive Processor)

> Sprockets runs the directive processor on each CSS and JavaScript
>   source file. The directive processor scans for comment lines beginning
>   with = in comment blocks **at the top of the file**

Comment: Sadly, it looks like you're right. Perhaps I'm going about this in the wrong way?

Comment: Take a look at swfobject code http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/source/browse/trunk/swfobject/src/swfobject.js - it's already wrapped in their own namespace `swfobject`.

Comment: its true, but i want that namespace within my own

Comment: ..anyway I'm afraid that without modifying the original library's source code you cannot wrap it in the namespace (or change the namespace).

Comment: ...so try this one `my.own.namespace.for.swfobject = swfobject`

Comment: yeah, that's what i was afraid i'd have to do. seems messy (and hard to maintain for lots of libs), but it will work.  thanks for you time.